# boto dynamodb batch_get TypeError

Tags: python, boto, amazon-dynamodb

I am getting

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

when I try to run the example from the [boto documentation](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/dynamodb2.html#module-boto.dynamodb2.table):

```
results = mytable.batch_get(keys=[{'username':'johndoe'},{'username':'jane'},{'username':'fred'},])
for res in results:
    print res['username']
```

I don't see anything I could have done wrong, but obviously there is something.

Any suggestions?
edit, adding stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testdynamolocal.py.bak", line 25, in <module>
    for res in results:
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-        packages/boto/dynamodb2/results.py", line 62, in __next__
    self.fetch_more()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/results.py", line 183, in fetch_more
    results = self.the_callable(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/table.py", line 1337, in _batch_get
    'Keys': [],
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Would it be possible to provide the entire stack trace for the error? It would help debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a mistake in getting 'mytable', posting here in case anyone else has a similar bad time:
I was doing this:

```
for table in tables.values():
    mytable = Table(table, connection=conn)
    results = mytable.batch_get(keys=[{'username':'johndoe'},{'username':'jane'},{'username':'fred'},])
```

...

But 'table' was getting a list instead of a string from tables.values(), so this works:

```
mytable = Table(table[0], connection=conn)
```

I am not thrilled with where the error was actually surfacing, but totally a problem I should have seen earlier.